# No root filesystem is defined while installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 using a USB flash drive on an Asus K401UQ laptop - i7 6th gen, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD + 24GB SSD.

I have left enough unallocated space to install Ubuntu using the - diskmgmt.msc - Windows 10 application.

The problem is I can't find the hard disk when I try to install it as shown in the below screenshots.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused by the UEFI settings in your BIOS that gives Win 10 full control. You need to modify the EFI settings and disable Secure Boot feature. It should give you access to the drive.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've already disabled the Secure Boot feature but the same problem. i can boot with Ubuntu Setup with any problem but in the partition section i cant find partitions of the hard drive.

Comment: Are you using a hybrid hard drive?

Comment: yes , 1 TB HDD & 25 GB SSD

Comment: The hybrid drive will make this a bit tricky. 

Boot the PC using the Ubuntu live session drive. Open **Disks** and see if you can find the drive. It should display the drive on the left hand side. 
If you can't see the drives on **Disks** it is possible that Ubuntu can't recognise it.

This could be caused by Ubuntu not having the right drivers for the hard drive or Windows might have encrypting the drive.